# Exchange 2010 - Error Sending to External domain

Tags: exchange-2010

I've added a new email address (new domain) to a mailbox, but it turns out they dont want it, so we are leaving the domain on the other external Exchange server, ive removed the address.
The issue is that the user is trying to send to this domain (as it currently exists externally) but exchange now wont send to this domain, as I assume it thinks the address is internal, any ideas how to resolve this?

Error:
550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found

Comment: Did you do all of this today?  It's likely that the OAB isn't updated yet.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to remove the domain as an accepted domain, either from the console Organization Configuration > Hub Transport or from the shell using Remove-AcceptedDomain.

Comment: Hi, nope its not in the accepted domain list

Comment: Does the user have this email address? Does the email address exist on the user object?

Comment: OK, but it must have been in the accepted domains list in order to assign the address to the user initially.  Have you restarted the hub transport service since removing the domain?